# Visual studio disappearing menu

Tags: visual-studio, menu

As I develop an application in Visual Studio 2010, every so often, the application's main menu strip disappears.

In the past I panicked, and then rebuilt the menu from scratch in the design view.

These days, I no longer panic. Instead, I find the Main Menu declaration in the [applicationName].Designer.cs file, which normally looks like this:

```
    // mainMenus
    // 
    this.mainMenus.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.fileMenuItem,
        this.viewMenuItem,
        this.helpMenuItem});
    this.mainMenus.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.mainMenus.Name = "mainMenus";
    this.mainMenus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1008, 24);
    this.mainMenus.TabIndex = 17;
    this.mainMenus.Text = "menuStrip1";
```

instead looks like this:

```
    // mainMenus
    // 
    this.mainMenus.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.mainMenus.Name = "mainMenus";
    this.mainMenus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1008, 24);
    this.mainMenus.TabIndex = 17;
    this.mainMenus.Text = "menuStrip1";
```

So I manually edit that file to restore the missing

```
    this.mainMenus.Items.AddRange line.
```

(Yes, I know you're not supposed to edit the [applicationName].Designer.cs file, because it's generated by Visual Studio. Still, that does fix it.)

My question is: any idea why the main menu strip keeps on disappearing? and how to prevent it from happening in the future?

Comment: This is caused by exceptions that are raised by code at design time.  Start by removing try/catch statements from your code so you can actually see them.